# Where were Yaakov's own animals when his wives' were divided into two camps?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, vayishlach

At [the beginning of *Vayishlach*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0132), *Yaakov* divides his possessions into two camps. [*Chizkuni*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14034&pgnum=42), seemingly bothered by [*Rashi*](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227/showrashi/true#v9)'s question about the gender of "המחנה האחת", explains that it means (not "the one <sub>[FEMININE]</sub> camp" but) "the camp of the one <sub>[FEMININE]</sub>": *Yaakov* divided his camp into the camp of *Lea* and the camp of *Rachel*. Not that his wives themselves were divided — [we see](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%90) that all his wives were together — but, rather, [*targum Yonasan*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%97) says, "למוהבות לאה ולמוהבות רחל", the two camps were "the gifts of *Lea* and the gifts of *Rachel*". I suppose this refers to whatever gifts they got from their family when they married or when they left with *Yaakov*, or other possessions of their own. (If anyone knows of a sourced explanation for what *Yonasan* means, though, I'd appreciate it.) My question is: [*Yaakov* himself had amassed a good deal of property](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%92), and [he had it with him](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%97), too. Which of the two camps did his own property go into, and, more critically, why is the division described as being between the wives' property? And if, as @Menachem suggests in a comment, there were three camps (one of *Lea*'s property, one of *Rachel*'s and one of the family), then why does the *Tora* say there were but two?

Comment: according to this interpretation, were there actually 3 camps? 1)gifts of leah, 2) gifts of rachel, 3) all the wifes (and kids) together?

Comment: @Menachem, maybe: I'll edit the question.

Comment: see this answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12067/1561

Answer (score 3):

Rashi ([Bereshit 31:33](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8226/showrashi/true#v33)), says:

> **Jacob’s tent:** That is, Rachel’s tent, for Jacob was usually with her, and so Scripture states: (below, 46:19): “The sons of Rachel, Jacob’s wife.” In reference to all of them, however, it does not say,“Jacob’s wife.” - [from Gen. Rabbah 74:9]

So perhaps the same thing applies here and Yaakov's stuff is included with Rachel's stuff.